# Can we use <body> within <body>? If yes then tag replace the outer with its classes?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I am building ASP.NET MVC project and sharing _Layout.cshtml file with all views. Every page has different bootstrap classes for customization. Can I make `<body>` in all other files? Will it replace the outer `<body>`?

I am using Razor views.

Comment: Why don't you give it try by yourself and see the results? In my understanding, having two `<body>` tags is invalid markup.

Comment: Even though if you create two <body> it will not show any error. But whatever <style> you applied for parent <body> will be inherited for all the pages, not the child <body>.